# Explain the order of elements in $\mathbb Z_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

*I cannot understand the cardinality of elements in modular classes like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/199xC.png) explained, source of the latter is [C1080](https://mycourses.aalto.fi/course/view.php?id=7531&section=2).*

[image]

**Definitions**

1. $\mathbb Z_{12}=\{\overline 0,\overline 1,\ldots, \overline{11}\}$
2. $\#\langle a \rangle = \# \{ a^n \mid n\in\mathbb Z \}$
3. By [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality), the cardinality is the number of elements in the set. For example, $\# \{1,2,3\}=3$ because of having 3 elements.

**Misunderstandings**

1. $\mathbb Z_{12}$, $a=1$, $\#\langle 1 \rangle = \# \{ 1^n \mid n\in\mathbb Z \}=12?$ Why not 1? Why $$\#\langle 1\rangle =\#\{1\} \ne 1?$$
2. $G=\mathbb Z_{12}$. $\#\langle 3\rangle =\{ 3^0, 3^1, 3^2, 3^3, 3^4, \ldots \} \cup U_- = \{ 1,3,9,3,9,3,\ldots \}\cup U_-=\{1,3,9\}\cup U_-$ where $$U_-=\{3^{-1}, 3^{-2}, 3^{-3}, 3^{-4}, \ldots\}$$ that has no zero element in $\langle 3\rangle$ by the above definition II?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group operation is addition, not multiplication.  There are twelve multiples of 1, not powers of 1.

Comment: The question to the original question is *"What is the order of $\mathbb Z_{12}$? What are the orders of each of the members in $\mathbb Z_{12}$? List all generators of $\mathbb Z_{12}$."* How can you know from this question that the topic is additive group, not multiplicative group. +1 for the observation, it explains the disparity, thank you +1

Comment: @hhh: $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is not a group under modular multiplication at all, since $0\cdot 1\equiv 0\cdot 2$, so the cancellation law (implied by the existence of inverses) would fail.

Comment: @hhh: I'm not sure what more to say. $(\mathbb Z_{12},\times)$ is _not a group_, so when someone says "the group $\mathbb Z_{12}$", they are obviously speaking about $(\mathbb Z_{12},+)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm my Algebra [book](http://solmu.math.helsinki.fi/2010/algebra.pdf) like p.63 uses multiplicative signs so I have mistakenly thought them to refer to products $\times$, instead of $+$, but now I clearly have to think them in cases like this as additions, thank you for pointing this out, easy confusion. So I understand this so that the subgroup criteria, subgroup test -- can all be understood also in the case of additive groups, not just multiplicative groups.